# Does my Remote Light bulb use power when not turned on?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bulb, light

I just recently bought an RGB light bulb which comes with a remote and I was wondering if you turn it off with the remote but you leave the switch on does it still consume power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but we're talking minimal usage. The bulb has to listen for your remote so it's using something.

Comment: Worth measuring how much, though: depending on the quality of the design, it could be anywhere from microwatts to a watt or more.

Comment: @Mark [This thread](http://cocoontech.com/forums/topic/10326-power-consumption-of-automated-light-switches-when-off/) from years ago (about automated switches) showed X10 lamp remote switches (similar technology) at 0.1A and 0.02W. I would expect about the same from a modern bulb